# How to resize horizontal jtree java swing by mouse when application is running?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'm a new Java Swing programer, I've got java basic. I want to create a form include jtree, jtree can be resized horizontal by mouse when application is running. How can I do that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Start by taking a look at [How to use split panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html)

Comment: Great! I'll try it now ^_^